# Radon Nikodym derivative on sum of measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let $m$ be a probability measure on $X$ and $\nu$ be a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure. $m=m_c+m_s$ be the Lebesgue decomposition of $m$ with respect to $\nu$. Let $\phi$ be a homeomorphism of $X$ such that $m \circ \phi$ is absolute continuous wrt to $m$ with Radon- Nikodym derivative $f$  and $\nu$ is $\phi$ invariant. I want to prove that $dm_c\circ \phi=fdm_c$ and $dm_s\circ \phi=fdm_s$. In the proof I saw the follwing steps.

I have $dm\circ\phi=fdm=fd(m_c+m_s)=fdm_c+fdm_s$- Is this expression true?
That is if $\mu=\mu_1+\mu_2$, then is the differential expression makes $d\mu=d\mu_1+
d\mu_2$?

Also what is mean by the statement $dm\circ\phi=dm_c\circ\phi+dm_s\circ\phi$. Now by the uniqueness of Lebesgue decompisition the proof follows. For that I need to prove both $fdm_c$ and $m_c\circ\phi$ are both absolutely continuous wrt $\nu\circ \phi=\nu$ and $fdm_s$ and $m_s\circ \phi$ are both singular wrt to $\nu\circ \phi=\nu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $fd\mu_1+fd\mu_2=fd(\mu_1+\mu_2)$ is immediate from definition: $\int_E fd(\mu_1+\mu_2)=\int_Ed\mu_1+\int_Efd\mu_2$.

$fdm_c << m_c$ by definition and $m_c << \nu$ so $fdm_c << \nu$.

$m_c\circ \phi \leq m\circ \phi$ and $m\circ \phi << \nu$ so $m_c\circ \phi <<\nu$.

There exists $E$ such that $m_s(E^{c})=0$ and $\nu (E)=0$. Let $F=\phi^{-1}(E)$. Then $\nu (F)=0$ and $(m_s\circ \phi) (F^{c})=0$. Hence $m_s \circ \phi $ is singular w.r.t. $\nu$.

Comment: What is the meaning of the statement $dm\circ\phi=dm_c\circ\phi+dm_s\circ\phi$? Because if we write a measure as $fd\mu$, that means $fd\mu(E)=\int_Efd\mu$. What does it mean simply $d\mu$?

Comment: @AAh It simply means $m\circ\phi=m_c\circ\phi+m_s\circ\phi$.

Comment: simply does $d\mu$ makes meaning?

Comment: $fd\mu$ is the measure $\tau$ defined by $\tau (E)=int_E fd\mu$. When $f=1$ this becomes $\mu$. There is no need to write $d\mu$ for this since it is same as $\mu$ but some people do.